# ExpressJS require() load order and Mongoose missing ModelSchema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm learning the MEAN stack and have found myself with a load order issue that doesn't seem to make sense.

The below code shows my server.js loading the routes file, which in turn pulls in the controller for a model, which in turn requires the model itself.

If I don't include a reference to the model from routes.js I get a MissingSchemeError when I startup the server.  Why?  Am I missing something regarding the loading of resources?

My understanding was that the exports for a file would be completely imported by the require() prior to attempting to run any code.

server.js

```
// modules =================================================
var express             = require('express');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride  = require('method-override');
var mongoose            = require('mongoose');
var morgan              = require('morgan');
var app                 = express();
// configuration ===========================================

// config files
var db = require('./config/db');

// set our port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 

// connect to our mongoDB database 
mongoose.connect(db.url); 

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

// set morgan to log requests
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app);
```

routes.js

```
//this line is the problem. why is this needed?
var Customer = require('./models/customer'); // <--
var customers = require('./controllers/customer-server-controller');


module.exports = function(app) {

    app.route('/api/customers')
        .get(customers.list);
        //.post(customer.create);

}
```

customer-server-controller.js

```
var     mongoose = require('mongoose');
var     Customer = mongoose.model('Customer');

/**
 * List of Customers
 */
exports.list = function(req, res) { 
    Customer.find().sort('-created').exec(function(err, customers) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: "ERROR: " + err
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(customers);
        }
    });
};
```

---

Got a good portion of the biolerplate from [this tutorial on Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular)

Comment: Why do you even need Customer model in routes.js? You need it only in customer controller.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're missing the model from the tutorial

You should have this somewhere.

## Create a models folder and add todo.js and add the following:

```
 // define model =================
    var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
        text : String
    });
```

Comment: No, I'm using my own model (Customer), which is referenced at the top of the controller file.  As I said, it works fine with my model if I put the require statement at the top of routes.js AND the controller.

Comment: What if you move your routes requirement in the first few lines? Mainly before mongoose is called?

Answer (score 0):

Your `customer-server-controller.js` doesn't `require()` the model file, it just tries to reference the model by asking Mongoose for it (Mongoose doesn't load the model file for you!):

```
var Customer = mongoose.model('Customer');
```

You need to `require()` the module file from your controller, otherwise the model isn't registered with Mongoose and you get the error that you got.

Comment: That's interesting. The docs indicate you are correct, but the reason I used that call instead of a require() is front reading meanJS code. Will update it tonight and test.  Thanks :)